# Java1.5 ExitOnOutOfMemory?

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jvm, command-line-arguments

I am having a problem making my java instance recognize command line CrashOnOutOfMemoryError
or ExitOnOutOfMemoryError

any ideas to get the supported command line that will do the required feature

Regards,

Comment: I am using java 1.5 as the title states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Unless you're using Java 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u92-relnotes-2949471.html) (specifically, **1.8u92** or newer), these command-line options are unavailable to you.

The only realistic thing one *could* do would be to catch either an `OutOfMemoryError` and call `System.exit(1)`, but that would be considerably *less* desirable.